# How to save Opaque true/false or set to null

Tags: java, swing, null, save, load

Currently i have a bunch of settings saved using configProps.setProperty for example:

```
configProps.setProperty("p.color",
            Integer.toString(p.getBackground().getRGB()));
```

the code above saves the current set colour of my background for my panel but what if I set the panel to transparent. how to I save weather the background is set to Opaque false or null.

I Know that

```
configProps.setProperty
```

works only with strings but I am unsure of a way to get a string for Opaque or null.

any help would be great thanks

Comment: `Properties#getProperty` can return `null` if the property you are looking for or you can use [`Properties#getProperty(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which can used to return a `defaultValue` when no value exists for the key.  Assuming you're storing `boolean` values, you can also use `Boolean.toString` and `Boolean.parse`

Comment: Thanks for your comment this has helped allot still unsure how to get the opaque. I now have configProps.setProperty("nocolor", Boolean.toString(p.) but i don't know how to get if its set to false or true currently scrolling through the options now.

Comment: Nevermind i think i may have found it p.isOpaque

Comment: now testing String invis = configProps.getProperty("nocolor");
  Boolean vis = new Boolean (Boolean.parseBoolean(invis));